# Exact match for words (mix of word and non-word characters) using regex in Text Editor like Notepad++ or Emeditor

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have below lines of Iogs to work on.

```
date time time-taken cs(Referer) x-cs(Referrer) x-cs(Referrer)-certs ...
```

I am parsing this huge log, almost 2 GB file. I have to replace this line of header for some reason. The fields are huge in number.

The challenges are -

1. If I use word boundary regex,  `\btime\b`, it matches '`time-taken`' too. And it should as '`-`' is non-word character. But how to overcome it? I want to exactly match each header field.
2. Sameway '`cs(Referer)`', it has its presence in '`x-cs(Referer)`' and many places.

So the purpose is to exactly match these hybrid words (word and non-word characters). Exactly match each word as its own.

Comment: It's not clear as to what EXACTLY you want to match. Please mention so for your sample input outputs, and also what a 'header' is.

Comment: I have to exactly match each word in the below line using regex in Notepad++ or Emeditor.


--------------------------------------------
date time time-taken cs(Referer) x-cs(Referrer) x-cs(Referrer)-certs

Comment: Again, it's not really clear what each word is separated by. If you include a list of separators like `-, <space>` etc. and some characters which should NOT be counted as separators, like `(, )` it would be much easier to clarify your doubt.

Comment: This is the line. Delimiter is space.

<date time time-taken cs(Referer) x-cs(Referrer) x-cs(Referrer)-certs>

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have stated in the comments, I think this will solve your issue:

```
(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=))[^\s]+(?=\s|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/6L1NRM/2

## Explanation -

`(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=))` tells the regex that whatever is matched should be preceded by either a space or the beginning of the line. In my previous answer, I had used `(?<=\s|^)`, but it didn't work because Notepad++ doesn't support variable length look-behinds.

`[^\s]+` searches for one-or-more non-space characters (in your case, the text to be matched)

`(?=\s|$)` tells the regex that the match should be followed by either a space or the end of the line.

Comment: It worked Robo Mop. Thank You. If you can help me understand it more easily.  :)